# Kendo UI Multiselect + ServerFiltering + ServerPaging with initial values

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I am having some problems with the Kendo UI Multiselect with enabled ServerFiltering and Serverpaging. I'm using a pagesize of 50 elements. If I set an initial value on pageload which is within these first 50 elements everything works fine. If I'm using a value thats not in the first 50 elements ( by using `multiSelect.data("kendoMultiSelect").value([1, 2, 99]])` ) it just ignores this value which is not in the preloaded list.

Is there any workaround or flag i can use to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/combobox/virtualization

With a virtual mapper there is a possibility to tell Kendo UI to preload the pages on which the initialized values can be found.